# Initializing Direct3D.Device throws GraphicsException with E_NOTIMPL

Tags: c#, directx, visual-studio-2015, direct3d

I do an application in C# using DirectX SDK. It worked but after OS reinstall, it don't.
When I try to initialize Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D.Device, it throws Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D.GraphicsException
ErrorCode: -2147467263 (0x80004001)
ErrorString: E_NOTIMPL

Windows Embedded 8.1 Industry Pro (but it used to work on the same system earlier - before reinstall)

Visual Studio 2015 Community (or Visual Studio 2013 Professional - the same problem)

Here is the code:

```
        PresentParameters pp = new PresentParameters();
        pp.SwapEffect = SwapEffect.Discard;
        pp.Windowed = true;
        device = new Device(0, DeviceType.Hardware, this, CreateFlags.SoftwareVertexProcessing, pp);
```

Comment: Note that the Managed DirectX 1.1 assemblies (the only way you can use DirectX from C# with the legacy DirectX SDK) have been deprecated for ages. I strongly recommend moving to something supported such as [SlimDX](http://www.slimdx.org/) or [SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/). See [DIrectX and .NET](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2010/12/09/directx-and-net.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I just found my mistake. I have the device in a Control and the Control wasn't in any Form. After I've added the Control to the main Form, it works.
Here is the code exemple:

```
public Form1()
{
  //Some other staff
  this.Controls.Add(myDirect3DControl);
  //After that I can initialize the device
}
```